# sort in unix, command not found error

Tags: sorting, unix, awk

I have one homework and I couldn't figure out what i am missing. I started with showing only department number 100. It shows department number 100 but also for every single line it says command not found.

This is my code:

```
awk  '/:100:/ { print }' employees
```

[The records in this file have 5 fields separated by colons (:). The fields are ssn, department, lastname, firstname and years_employed.
Use the employees file to create output where the employees are from DEPARTMENT 100 only, the number of years_employed has been increased by 1 year and the file is in sorted order.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLECV.png)

Comment: Please include a sample input in text (not picture), and the expected output. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using putty

Comment: That command alone **cannot** produce the error message `command not found`. Your problem is in some pat of your code that you haven't shared with us and so we can't do much to help you.

Comment: if your data was created or passed-thru an MS Windows environment (including `ftp`) to Linux, then try `dos2unix employees`, then try your `awk` code again. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.